# CIDetectorTypeRectangle to detect multiple rectangles

Tags: image, camera, detection, cidetector

when using CIDetectorTypeRectangle I can only (hardly) detect only one rectangle in my camera image, but I want to detect multiples rectangles. Its possible to detecte multiple rectangle as is possible to detect multiple faces ??

Answer (score 5):

I run into the same issue when using CIDetectorTypeRectangle. I wasn't able to get more than 1 feature out of `featuresInImage(image)`. In the Apple Developer docs there is no remark regarding the maximum number of returned features, but I may have found some evidence in the wwdc 2014 sessions (http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/514).

> [...] So we've created a generic rectangle detector object and it takes one
>   option parameter which is the aspect ratio that we want to search for.
>
> And again, you can ask the detector to return the features array.
>
> Now right now, it just returns one rectangle but that may change in
>   the future. [...]

Hopefully someone can falsify this assumption, otherwise I have to stuck with openCV2 for rectangle detection.

Comment: As of iOS 9.1, it detects only a single rectangle.